# Connect 8 Raspberry pi to MATLAB using Ethernet switch

Tags: pi-3, ethernet, matlab

I have 8 Raspberry Pi 3 and want to connect them to MATLAB (installed in my laptop) using Ethernet 16 port switch (NETGEAR).
The idea is that RasPis do some processing and send data in real-time to MATLAB through the Ethernet switch.
I have no idea how to connect them together and assign fixed IP address to each one of them so I can use the same IP each time to connect.

any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You said, "I have no idea how to connect them together and assign fixed IP address... ". The thing that will come to mind when people read that is that [you didn't expend enough effort doing your own research.](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). And without trying to sound pedantic, it occurs to me that perhaps a simpler setup might be a better place to start, and gain experience. In other owrds, maybe start with a single RPi, figure out how to set its IP address, connect it to MATLAB, etc before adding 9 more. In other words, break the problem down into manageable steps.

Answer (score 1):

While this question seems to have been ask without much prior research nor effort, you are going to at least have to set up a DHCP server someone on the network that these are all attached to, whether that be on their own (Have one be a Host and the rest Nodes) or on your own network with a router (that will usually have a DHCP server running). This way you can assign unique IP addresses to your nodes (Static).

All the experience I have with MATLAB is in my ECE courses which involve signalling and not RaspberryPis, but if you want easy of use there are a few Python libraries you could use.

I would strongly recommend [DisPy](http://dispy.sourceforge.net) since you seem to be a beginner. I found this library very easy to understand and get up and running. This would at least get you started with distributed computing across your 8 Pi's but you might have to do some research for then connecting DisPy to your MATLAB computer. E.g. connecting the host pi (or computer) could then run some python to connect MATLAB to the code running on the clustered Pi's.